# Isn't this supposed to run for single time range(3,3,2) python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a prime number program in python. But when user inputs 3. My program is not working. Further checking with print statements i found its not going in for loop.

Comment: start is 3 stop is 3 and step is 2, can you explain how that should work? What is between 3 and 3? Do you mean  you want to start at 3 and take a step of 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume in your program you have `range(3,i,2)`, where `i` is the input. When your user inputs 3, there will be no range since you're going from 3 to 3.

A good way to fix this is at the beginning of the function. Before you get your range, return `[2,3]` if the input is 3 (I assume you are doing something similar for 2)

Comment: Thanks, 1st day with python. Fixed with this
range(1 if loop_end == 3 else 3, loop_end, 2)

Comment: @DhruvGaba Honestly I didn't even know that was valid syntax. The more you know...